# Sounds not playing on PhoneGap 1.5 for Android (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova

I have an App made with phonegap (Cordova 1.5). The audio is in wav format and mp3 format, and is never being reproduced.

Does android require a different file format or some kind of configuration for audio files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't. I am running cordova, zepto on a galaxy tab and i'm getting the beeps.

The example project in the android folder, if you look at the index, has a button labeled beep. This is the audio.

button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="beep();">Beep</a>
```

js:

`var beep = function() {
    navigator.notification.beep(2);
};`